# How to have Server Name in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a college student studying SQL Server and I installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

My question is where can I get a Server Name for this Management Studio? I tried a lot of names but they not accept...

What would I do?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a server? Or are you already connected and want to know the server name?

Comment: you should have installed it with installation...

Comment: What do you mean you tried a lot names but they do not accept??? Are you trying to connect to sql server? Are you trying to install it? Some clarity in your question would go a long towards a clear answer.

Comment: <computer name>\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: You need to figure out what you actually installed. "I installed MS SQL Server 2008 or Management Studio"... These two things are are not the same. If you installed Server it would have asked you for an instance name during the install.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you have

> **Sql Server started in services**. **[Control Panel>Administrative  Tools>Services> Sql Server.**

2. Add server name as

> **.\sqlexpress** or **localhost\sqlexpress**, or **(local)\sqlexpress**

3. Select Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to connect.

To see which instances you have installed on your computer (can be several):

> - expand the server name select list
> - click the last option "Browse for more..."
> - on Local Servers tab expand "Database engine"
> - click on server name

It's usually **COMPUTER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS**.